# How to use coverflow control in my Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, xaml, coverflow

I am planning to use coverflow control in my Silverlight application, but I am not able to  find the cover flow control in the Silverlight XAML controls tool kit.

Also right click on the "Tools pane > Choose XAML components tools >" but still the cover floe control is not there in the Silverlight library

Can anyone provide me solutions to get the Microsoft Silverlight coverflow control in to my toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such control in Silverlight. Maybe this project on CodePlex does what you want. http://silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com/